# Count distinct values in mongodb then count sum

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

**I have a sample document here from my mongodb:**

```
blood_group:A,
blood_category:whole blood,
num_stock:11

blood_group:B,
blood_category:whole blood, 
num_stock:10

blood_group:AB,
blood_category:platelet,
num_stock:10
```

**How can I count the values of total** `num_stock` **with distinct values** `blood_category`, **I'm expecting like this:**

```
[ { blood_category: whole blood, count: 21 },
  { blood_category: platelet, count: 10 }
]
```

**What I tried:**

```
 router.get('/blood', function(req, res) {
       Blooddonation.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$blood_category" , count :{$sum:1}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}],function(err, blood) {     
       res.json({ success: true, date: blood });
    });           
 });
```

**using the sample above, yields to:**

```
[{blood_category: 'whole blood', count:2},
{blood_category: 'platelet', count:1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `count :{$sum:"$num_stock"}`

```
 router.get('/blood', function(req, res) {
       Blooddonation.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$blood_category" , count :{$sum:"$num_stock"}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}],function(err, blood) {     
       res.json({ success: true, date: blood });
    });           
 });
```

sample collection

```
> db.xoxo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3d4b84d74266980e8db1bc"), "blood_group" : "A", "blood_category" : "whole blood", "num_stock" : 11 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3d4b84d74266980e8db1bd"), "blood_group" : "B", "blood_category" : "whole blood", "num_stock" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3d4b84d74266980e8db1be"), "blood_group" : "AB", "blood_category" : "platelet", "num_stock" : 10 }
```

result

```
> db.xoxo.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$blood_category", count : {$sum : "$num_stock"}}}])
{ "_id" : "platelet", "count" : 10 }
{ "_id" : "whole blood", "count" : 21 }
>
```

Comment: it's returning [object Object]

Comment: the result should be only two: wholeblood: 21 and platelet:10